# how to read csv and stored the data into mongoDB using awk

Tags: bash, mongodb, awk, gawk

i have 2 csv file(10gb each file)

a.csv

```
  23,88,564
  21,56,461
```

b.csv

```
  23,88,1145
  21,56,5763
```

collection should be like

```
      {
"_id" : ObjectId("589b264efbb76e87b3611f3d"),
"longitude" : 23,
"latitude" : 88,
"band_4" : 564,
"band_8" : 1145
       }
      {
"_id" : ObjectId("589b264efbb76e87b3611f3d"),
"longitude" : 21,
"latitude" : 56,
"band_4" : 461,
"band_8" : 5763
       }
```

data should be imported line by line in mongoDB collection...can anybody help me out in this

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/ ?..

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$1 OFS $2]=$3; 
    next
}
(($1 OFS $2) in a) {
    print "{";print "\"longitude\" : " $1; 
    print "\"latitude\" : " $2;
    print "\"band_4\" : " $3;
    print "\"band_8\" : " a[$1 OFS $2];print "}"
}' a b
```

Outputs:

```
{
"longitude" : 23
"latitude" : 88
"band_4" : 1145
"band_8" : 564
}
{
"longitude" : 21
"latitude" : 56
"band_4" : 5763
"band_8" : 461
}
```

Comment: actually i want to import the data after the importing the mongo collection should look like this...     {
"_id" : ObjectId("589b264efbb76e87b3611f3d"),
"longitude" : 21,
"latitude" : 56,
"band_4" : 461,
"band_8" : 5763
       }

Comment: @gauravsingh just add the extra info in the first print of last bloc (instead of only `"{"`), the code concept stay the same

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FPAT="(^[^,]*,[^,]*)|([^,]*$)"; split( "longitude latitude band_4 band_8", N)}

     FNR==NR{ F[$1]=$0; next}

     ($1 in F) { 
         split( F[$1]","$2, D, /,/)
         print "       {\n\"_id\" : ObjectId(\"589b264efbb76e87b3611f3d\"),"
         for (i=1; i<=4;i++) printf( "\"%s\" : %d,\n", N[i], D[i])
         print "       }"
         }
    ' file1 file2
```

- need awk 4 for FPAT (`awk --version`) taht define content of field to the opposite of FS that specify "what is not in field"